# Loading javascript/css on login form page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I am using forms authentication, and when the user is not authenticated he automatically gets sent to:

> login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebForm1.aspx

When this happens, I cannot load any javascript or css. Instead of GET'ing

> Resources/myScript.js

it seems to be GET'ing

> login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fResources%2fmyScript.js

This obviously causes some problems. And I don't know how to solve it...

**Edit:** I include the script in `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you including the js file in your page? Could you add that to your question?

Comment: please share some code snippets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude your css and javascript files from authentication.

Add this in your web.config where css is the path to your css files (do the same for your javascript files)

```
<location path="css">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your folder Resources or the file you don't want to be authenticated inside your web.config as below:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      // system.web configuration settings.
   </system.web>
   <location path="Resources/myScript.js">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```